# Query Professors and Salaries greater than the minimum of specific a department

Tags: mysql, database

Given this Schema:

```
Professor_ID
Professor_Name
Dept_ID
Salary


Dept_ID
Dept_Name
```

A university uses 2 data tables, Professor and Departments, to store data about its professor and the departments associated with each major.

Write a query to print the name and salary for each professor:

1. Professor does not work in the Art department
2. Professor's salary is greater than smallest salary of any professor in the Art department

Sample Output:

```
Joe Smith  22066

Ken Doe 13411

Eliott Scott 19404

Scott Thompson 48299
```

I just tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT Professor_ID, Professor_Name, Dept_ID, Salary
FROM Professors p  
INNER JOIN Departments d
ON p.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID
WHERE Dept_Name != 'Art'and Salary > (SELECT MIN(Salary))
   FROM Professors p 
   INNER JOIN Departments d 
   ON p.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID  
   WHERE Dept_Name = 'Arts and Humanities')
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this on your own? Additionally, please specify sample input and expected output data

Comment: Work through [SQL Zoo](https://sqlzoo.net/) tutorial and you will be able to solve such problems.

Comment: 'Greater than smallest salary' is an odd request

Comment: @Strawberry- the problem compares salaries **outside** of Art department to the smallest  **in** Art.

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried using multiple JOINs because from my understanding, we will have to  grab all the salaries and another join to grab all the salaries larger from the Art department? Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Strawberry would I need to use a ON to link the p.department_id = d.department_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you that

The portion of the final query tagged ---1 will give you all the salaries of professors that are not in art department
The portion of the final query tagged ---2 will compare the salaries of the professors selected in the first portion and compare it with the smallest salary of professors in Art using the query below:

```
select min(Salary) from From Professors p inner join Departments d on p.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID  where Dept_Name = 'Art'
```

Final Query

```
--- 111
    select 
    Professor_ID,
    Professor_Name,
    Dept_ID,
    Salary
    From Professors p  inner join Departments d on p.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID
    where Dept_Name != 'Art'
--- 111
--- 222
    and Salary > (select min(Salary) From Professors p inner join Departments d on p.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID  where Dept_Name = 'Art')
--- 222
```

Comment: Right Nico, I edited my answer to add explanations. Hope its better

Comment: @zip Can you explain the double from From in the query tagged 2?

Answer (score -1):

```
Select p.name, p.salary from professor p inner join department d on p.department_id = d.id
where d.name <> 'Arts and Humanities' and p.salary > (
select min(p.salary) from professor p inner join department d on p.department_id = d.id
where d.name like '%Arts and Humanities%');
```